# Unable to access value of a pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int *x = new int;
*x = 5;

cout << x << endl;
delete[] x;
```

I am trying to dynamically allocate resources to a variable 'x'. I then assign the value '5' to it. When I try to print the value of 'x', I get some garbage value called 0x8321 and so on. I am sure that is not the value I assigned.

Any idea how I can access the value of x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `std::cout << *x << std::endl`.

The value that you are getting is the address of the memory (region) to where the pointer is pointing to.

**EDIT :** And use `delete x;` instead of `delete[] x;`.

Comment: also don't forget to `delete x;` instead of `delete[] x'`

Comment: Yes, made changes to the answer accordingly.

Comment: Using-directives in files where main function is defined isn't bad practice, often the opposite, i.e. using _std::_ all over the program is.

Comment: he was right. i was indeed using 'using namespace std'

Comment: See [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently printing the address of the pointer. If you want the value you should do
`cout << *x << endl`